# How to get access to the millisecond level clock?

Tags: python, time

I have the following piece of code

```
import time
time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

As you see the above will only print at the second level at most. So if I call this function twice within the same second then it will print the same value.

To have a further level of granularity how do I call the millisecond clock that runs within a particular second so that few milliseconds have passed by the time I call this function again and so I get a new value at the second call

Comment: Why don't you just use the POSIX time instead?

Comment: You can use [`datetime.strftime`’s `%f`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to get *microseconds*, if those are acceptable.